# Why do RGB values seem very high for my multispectral orthomosaic imagery?

Tags: arcgis-pro, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, rgb, orthophoto

I am using ArcGIS Pro (2.4.2) to analyze a 5-band multispectral image captured with a Matrice 200 (UAV). All image processing has been done with Agisoft Metashape, which includes calibrating spectral reflectance with a calibration panel and stitching the imagery together into a final orthomosasic.

When I look at the imagery in ArcGIS, I notice that my RGB values are very, very high. Much higher than the typical 0-255 RGB values that is expected for imagery. An example of the values that I am receiving is included below:

[image]

What is the reason for this, and how could I convert them back to the 0-255 range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your imagery is 16bit.  16bit data can contain a lot more information than 8bit.  The signed range of integer values that can be stored in 16 bits is −32,768 to 32,767 and the unsigned range is 0 to 65,535, while 8bit is 0-255 (unsigned).

8bit RGB is really only the end product, rendered for visualisation and pretty useless for analytical purposes. If you are planning any sort of analysis with the data, leave it in 16bit.